# How to lookup for Series in a Dataframe column

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have a series (str values) that I need to lookup in a dataframe column for presence and create a new column for each str value with 1/0 values. Below is how I am doing it, need help write a function to accomplish this task more efficiently. thanks

Tours, 
Breweries, 
Pizza, 
Restaurants, 
Food, 
Hotels & Travel,

```
Mydata['Tours'] = Mydata.categories.str.contains('Tours', regex=False)
Mydata['Breweries'] = Mydata.categories.str.contains('Breweries', regex=False)
Mydata['Pizza'] = Mydata.categories.str.contains('Pizza', regex=False)
Mydata['Restaurants'] = Mydata.categories.str.contains('Restaurants', regex=False)
Mydata['Food'] = Mydata.categories.str.contains('Food', regex=False)
Mydata['Hotels & Travel'] = Mydata.categories.str.contains('Hotels & Travel', regex=False)

Mydata['Tours'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
Mydata['Breweries'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
Mydata['Pizza'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
Mydata['Restaurants'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
Mydata['Food'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
Mydata['Hotels & Travel'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
```

Comment: Please label which is the input, which is the output

Comment: Thanks, the below solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need a `for` loop:

```
tags = ['Tours','Breweries','Pizza','Restaurants','Food','Hotels & Travel']

for tag in tags:
    Mydata[tag] = Mydata.categories.str.contains(tag, regex=False)
    Mydata[tag].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
```

BTW `lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0` is pretty much the same as `int`, I believe you could simply use `.astype(int)` (untested)

Comment: Thank you Julien! Exactly what I was looking for. The first part worked fine (created columns correctly with True/Falls). The second line is not working - doesn't convert the 6 new column values to 1/0.

Comment: The code runs fine but in my dataframe I still see True/Falls

Comment: Not sure what would be the exact syntax, but something like `Mydata[tag] = Mydata.categories.str.contains(tag, regex=False).astype(int)` or if you do it in 2 lines `Mydata[tag] = Mydata[tag].astype(int)` or `Mydata[tag].apply(int)`... something along of those should work...